# Paradox Sql Local Update with Case Statments

Tags: sql, local, paradox

i work with Paradox (SQL Local) and i want to Update two lines of one table with two differents values. I can do that with two updates commands but I want to do with ONE command.

Clearly I want to transform these two request :

```
 Update Table1 SET Lib = 'test1' where Code = 'Code1'
 Update Table1 SET Lib = 'test2' where Code = 'Code2'
```

in one request.

I try this :

```
Update Codiv Set Lib = 
                      (CASE Code WHEN 'Code1' THEN 'test1' 
                                 WHEN 'Code2' THEN 'test2'  ELSE Lib END)  
             Where Objet LIKE 'Object' AND Code  IN ('Code1', 'Code2')
```

But i have an error near the element "Code".

Comment: Why do you have a `*`? In this: `WHEN 'Code1' THEN 'test1' *`

Comment: Sorry just an error of copy/paste

Comment: Incorrect KeyWord, Element : Code

Comment: you need to wrap Code in the delimiter for paradox, I think it's " the parser is seeing Code as a keyword not column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paradox local SQL does not allow CASE statements.

Comment: Thanks, it's what i understand through all error i had when i try to include Case Statements.